# SQL, ORDER BY для сортировки хранящейся таблицы

Tags: sql, order

Здравствуйте!
Не могу сообразить, возможно ли в моей задаче произвести сортировку SQL запросом. Уж очень не хочется сортировать массивами вручную.

В бд хранится таблица по ячейкам:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача заключается в получении этой-же таблицы, отсортированной по значению **value**, у которого **column=3**
Таким образом, хотелось бы получить следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Реально ли выполнить эту задачу только средствами SQL?

Comment: join таблицы с самой собой по условию `a.row=b.row and b.column=3` после чего сортировка по полю b.values

Comment: нет, она не будет умножена на 2, ведь мы указываем условие b.column=3, значит у алиаса b для каждого row будет строго одна запись

Comment: Да, но join производит объединение. И в результате запроса мне вернется та-же таблица, умноженная на два.

Comment: Хм. Тогда я не верно понял. Запрос такого вида: SELECT * FROM `table` a JOIN `table` b ON a.row=b.row and b.column=3 ORDER BY b.value

Comment: да, именно так, что бы лишних колонок не было, я бы `select a.* ...` написал

Comment: Да, точно. Благодарю!

Answer (score 0):

Mike правильно подсказал, соединить на саму себя и отсортировать по второй:

```
SELECT а.* 
FROM table a 
JOIN table b ON a.row=b.row and b.column=3 
ORDER BY b.value;
```